# Excluding a file extension through wildcards

Tags: linux, wildcard

I have a directory which files with multiple extensions such as *.asc, *.txt.*.csv etc.
I am using this path in a script where I can only change the file names, which is passed through variable.

```
/home/myuser/mydirectory/{fileNameVariable}
```

I can pick all the .csvs by passing *.csv as the variable value or *.txt for respective files. However what I want to do is pick all files (.csv, .txt etc.) except *.asc.

Is there a way through using wildcard I can exclude only one file extension and pick the rest?

Comment: `grep -v ...`, does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *brace expansion* to select only the names and extensions you want and exclude any of the extensions not named. For example to locate all `.csv` and `.txt` files within a directory, you can use:

```
$ ls -al *.{csv,txt}    ## note: no space after the separating comma
```

If you had many `test1..., test2..., etc.` files and you only wanted to select the `test2*.csv` and `test2*.txt` files you could narrow the initial glob to:

```
$ ls -al test2*.{csv,txt}
```

Of course, you can use your path and variable name in place of `test2` above.